# How to show the TableView (like dropdown) on Button Click in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, button

I have tried this code. http://www.mediafire.com/download/bvoqrkn82sd6az9/tablesample.zip  ..Here, It will display the Table View. But I need to create a tableview whenever I click the button, it should display the list of Tableview like dropdown as it is in this screenshot. http://www.mediafire.com/download/7jiwb0e00916gh9/Table+View.PNG  This is what I need to display. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you can make it hidden on default, and on button click make your table view to be appeared

Comment: This is what I was stuck up. How could I do the button to be hidden and whenever I click it, it should open the tableview ?

Comment: select your tableview and then from your interface builder or interface panel check the check box with title hidden. make IBoutlet of your table and on button action set its hidden property to 'NO'

Comment: I haven't used storyboard here. All the controls UITable View are dynamic. That's what stucked to create a button there..

Comment: that will be more easy, every view has property `hidden` so when you create your tableview set its property to `YES` and on button click change its property to `NO`

Comment: do u want drop down table or expandable cell ...??

Comment: i think Dinesh wants a table view to be appeared when user clicks on button in Nav bar

Comment: Ya. Right muneeb. First of all, I need to create a button in nav bar. Can you please tell me how to do that? as like in the screenshot

Comment: simple place a button on the Nav bar and set the table initial Height as 0 and for uiview animate with delay 0.7 and height to required one

Comment: @Spynet: That's what I am stucking. Couldn't place a button in nav bar.

Comment: @DineshKumar do u need code or entire project ???

Comment: can you share the code how you are setting your navigation button?

Comment: This is the project I have done so far. http://www.mediafire.com/download/bvoqrkn82sd6az9/tablesample.zip  I need to create a button in nav bar and if I click the button, it should display the list of table view. Please edit in this code itself.

Comment: @DineshKumar task for me or muneebShabbir

Comment: @muneebShabbir r u doing this one

Comment: any of you can solve a problem please. Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: @spynet: no :p coz currently not working on mac projects so currently running windows

Comment: @Spynet: can you please?

Comment: @Spynet: Are you doing it bro?

Comment: I have added this code UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Right" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(method:)];          
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton; in viewdidload method of dkhomeviewcontroller.m..I have created a button. But I need to display the table view whenever I click the button

Comment: s i finished uploading

Comment: can you please provide me the link ?

Comment: i posted the answer pls check and update me.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40101/discussion-between-spynet-and-dinesh-kumar)

Comment: Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34586224/3908884

Answer (score 3):

You can change height of tableView with animation. Set time according  your suitability.

For Expansion:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationYourChoice
                         animations:^{
                            CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
                              frame.size.height = 300;
                             self.tableView.frame = frame;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
```

For shrinking:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationYourChoice
                         animations:^{
                            CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
                              frame.size.height = 0;
                             self.tableView.frame = frame;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for dropdwon in IOS SDK. If you need this follow like this.

1. On the click of this button you'll have to load a UIView or UITableView which will come exactly down to your UIButton.
2. This custom UIView or UITableView will act as your drop down.
3. Once your use is complete you can either hide it or remove it.

I hope it will hepl you.. Instead of dropview you can use **UIPopoverController** to show the **UITableView**

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this , You can achieve  this by adding the button on the first row of any section and load other rows by the click on the first row with `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` using beginUpdate.

So now every first row of the section with index==0 will be a dropdown button and other rows starting from index=1 will be your data rows representing the information.