# How to display the tableview in dropdown list on Button Click in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, buttonclick

I have tried this code. http://www.mediafire.com/download/bvoqrkn82sd6az9/tablesample.zip ..Here, I need like this.. whenever I click the show button, it should display the list of Tableview like dropdown as it is in this screenshot. When on load, table view should be hidden. When on click the button, tableview should display. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: This is what you need...Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628214/how-to-show-the-tableview-like-dropdown-on-button-click-in-iphone
Hope it will solve your answer!

Comment: Refer to this
https://github.com/satishazad/SAMenuDropDown

Answer (score 5):

You can change height of tableView with animation. Set time according your suitability.

For Expansion:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationYourChoice
                         animations:^{
                            CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
                              frame.size.height = 300;
                             self.tableView.frame = frame;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
```

For shrinking:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationYourChoice
                         animations:^{
                            CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
                              frame.size.height = 0;
                             self.tableView.frame = frame;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
```