# How to fix the Table view as Dialog or Popup For all View Controllers in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

Totally i have 5 view controllers and i have fixed one button as Account Button in all 5 view controllers, once i clicked the Account button it need to show the tablewView like below image,first i tried the one table view to show hide in first view controller i want to show the table view for all five view controller when i clicked the account button,

This i want to show in all view controllers,

[image]

When i click any option it navigate to

```
My Account -> AccountVC,
Track Order -> TrackOrderVC,
Customer Services ->CusServicesVC
```

Comment: where you are facing problem?

Comment: i developing app like shopping app so i want to show one view like the above image to all view controller when i click the account button

Comment: create custom view with shared instance and use single view in all pages

Comment: You can try this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628214/how-to-show-the-tableview-like-dropdown-on-button-click-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

same thing i implemented in one of my project.create subclass of uiview and in .h file write this two method

```
      - (void)showMenuViewAnimatedWithFrame:(CGRect)rect;
      - (void)hideMenuViewAnimated;
```

and in .m file create a object of table view implement it's delegate and datasource method and write this code as

```
- (void)showMenuViewAnimatedWithFrame:(CGRect)rect{

  listTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - 10);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    self.frame = rect;

    }];
 }

 - (void)hideMenuViewAnimated{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

    self.frame = preViewframe;//set your view frame to preViewframe
   }];
 }
```

finally call this methods in your view controller where you want to show a dropdown picker by creating its views object.if you set correctly i will look like:

[image]