# UITableViewCell with dropdown UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UITableView with 'n' number of rows. In each cell i am having one menu button. when i click on menu button I need to show one dropdown UITableView with 3 rows in every cell. How I can set the frame for dropdown UITableView. I am using objective c.

[image]

when I click on menu button I need to show report UITableView below the menu button on every cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the TableView (like dropdown) on Button Click in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628214/how-to-show-the-tableview-like-dropdown-on-button-click-in-iphone)

Comment: google it  , name : expand & collapse tableview, accordion table view, etc

Comment: please share more specific information if you have googled and not found anything relevant

Answer (score 0):

It's little complex one but not hard. luckly we have one library called [DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown). This make this task very easy.

Add `pod 'DropDown'` to your Podfile.

```
let dropDown = DropDown()

// The view to which the drop down will appear on
dropDown.anchorView = view // UIView or UIBarButtonItem in your case that menu button

// The list of items to display. Can be changed dynamically
dropDown.dataSource = ["Report"]

dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
  print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
}
dropDown.show()
```

In Objective-C

```
DropDown *dropDown = [[DropDown alloc] init];
dropDown.selectionAction = ^(NSInteger, NSString * _Nonnull) {
    //code
};
```

Library in Swift but you can use bridging header to use that in Objective C.
Hope this will help you

Comment: Can U please share this in objective c

Comment: Thank You @ Ganesh Manickam

Comment: you are welcome. If this solve your issue you can upvote this answer and mark it as answer for this question :)